# Is it appropriate to call inheritance as EXTEND of a class

Tags: c++, inheritance, definition

according to WordWeb dictionary "Extend" means "Increase in scope, range or area". So if we keep this thing in mind and do inheritance, then in that case the derived class simply increase attributes and functions of the base class. But actually while doing inheritance we change this concept. For example, in base class each internal functions can access it's private members, but in derived class this behaviour is changed, no derived class's functions can access it's parent's private data members. So please explain how and when we call "Inheritance" as "Extend" of base class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not entirely related, but in a way it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: Thanks for link. I think you somehow got my point, but I am not able to clearly relate it. Also Instead of just saying extending base class, don't we have to explicitly say all inheritance as "Partial Extend", because just saying "Extend" may not be correct?

Comment: I think you are sticking to the words too tightly. "Extend" is just a (key)word that makes one class inherit from another. I think "extend" is used because that usually the case - we have a class and we want to create another class that can do more. Also, your "change of concept" is also questionable. Yes, inside the subclass you have a little bit different concept, but from outside of the (sub)class, if the subclass complies with the substitution principle, the concept stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

In code you ARE able to access methods and properties of the base class.

If I got

```
public class A 
{
public void MakeSauce() {}
}
```

Then

```
public class B : A
{
public B()
{
MakeSauce();
}
}
```

is a valid constructor, where it's calling the method it inherited from A. However, as inherited class you're able to also give your own ''twist'' to MakeSauce.

I.e.

```
public class A 
{
public virtual void MakeSauce() { Console.WriteLine("I made sauce!"}
}
```

then

```
class B : A
{
   public B()
   {
      MakeSauce(); // call A's implementation
   }

   public override void MakeSauce() // override A implementation
   {
      Console.WriteLine("I made 2 gallons of sauce.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is private belongs to the class, so, it cannot be inherited. By inheritance you get access to everything that is public or accessible by other access modifiers. In easy words it means the inherited class is sharing what can be shared (private is private as the word says) with other class or classes that inherits it. I suggest you to read more about it as this is one of the basic concepts in Java or any other Object Orientated Languages (in fact this is not related to the language but to Object Orientated Programming).

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not related to concept of inheritance, but question is relating "Inheritance" with meaning of word "Extends". Because by doing inheritance we do not simply expand our base class but we are changing some internal behaviours too.